# Почему могут не переводиться слова? PHP

Tags: php

Выводится: Башенный-кран-QTZ-125.
Нужно: bashennyiy-kran-QTZ-125.
Если создавать переменную с текстом, то все работает, а вот при получении данных нет.

```
$product = $dbh->query("SELECT product_id FROM one")->fetchAll(2); 

$names = $dbh->query("SELECT product_id, name FROM two")->fetchAll(2); 

foreach($product as $item){
  $id = $item['product_id'];
  foreach($names as $nam) {
    if ($nam['product_id']  == $id) {
      $semantik = get_semantic_url($nam['name']);
      echo $semantik . "<br>";
    }
  }
}
function get_semantic_url($str1) {
    $tr = array(
        "А"=>"a","Б"=>"b","В"=>"v","Г"=>"g",
        "Д"=>"d","Е"=>"e","Ж"=>"j","З"=>"z","И"=>"i",
        "Й"=>"y","К"=>"k","Л"=>"l","М"=>"m","Н"=>"n",
        "О"=>"o","П"=>"p","Р"=>"r","С"=>"s","Т"=>"t",
        "У"=>"u","Ф"=>"f","Х"=>"h","Ц"=>"ts","Ч"=>"ch",
        "Ш"=>"sh","Щ"=>"sch","Ъ"=>"","Ы"=>"yi","Ь"=>"",
        "Э"=>"e","Ю"=>"yu","Я"=>"ya","а"=>"a","б"=>"b",
        "в"=>"v","г"=>"g","д"=>"d","е"=>"e","ж"=>"j",
        "з"=>"z","и"=>"i","й"=>"y","к"=>"k","л"=>"l",
        "м"=>"m","н"=>"n","о"=>"o","п"=>"p","р"=>"r",
        "с"=>"s","т"=>"t","у"=>"u","ф"=>"f","х"=>"h",
        "ц"=>"ts","ч"=>"ch","ш"=>"sh","щ"=>"sch","ъ"=>"y",
        "ы"=>"yi","ь"=>"","э"=>"e","ю"=>"yu","я"=>"ya"," - "=>"-"," – "=>"-","--"=>"-","---"=>"-","----"=>"-",
   "."=>""," "=>"-","?"=>"","/"=>"-","\\"=>"-","!"=>"",
   "*"=>"-",":"=>"-","*"=>"-","\""=>"-","<"=>"-",
   ">"=>"-","|"=>"-","»"=>"-","«"=>"-","#"=>"","$"=>"","("=>"",")"=>""
    );
    return strtr($str1 , $tr);
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: Вероятнее всего, что в БД у вас utf-8, а `strtr` не умеет в юникод